# E-newspaper website construction

Tags: php, html, asp.net, jsp-tags

im trying to make a website similar to this http://epaper.rajexpress.in but cant figure out how would be the CMS of this site, as there is one single image of the newspaper and this image is mapped and each mapped area is linked to another image, which is enlarged version of that mapped area.

thanks :)

Comment: Is this PHP, .NET, or JSP?

Answer (score 1):

This type of thing isn't the work of most CMSs on the market today. I suspect it requires a great deal of manual interaction to declare the regions of each part of this paper. Here's a work-flow though:

- User uploads full hi-res image
- Show a scaled-down, compressed, version on screen
- User clicks and drags to outline a region
- Coordinates and dimensions of this outline are stored
- Outlined portion of image is saved to separate file, and associated with coords/dimensions
- Repeat from step 3 until all regions accounted for

When building the layout itself, you load in a smaller, down-scaled image. Then you pull in the coordinates and dimensions of all selections from before. These should be based on % values, so they'll overlay the smaller full-page image nicely.

All overlays are `a` elements, dynamically sized and positioned. Each of them point to their respective image extracted from the hi-res image initially uploaded.

This should be enough to get you started. Best of luck.

Comment: how can user select an area and save coordinates of selected region online??

Comment: You would have to build an interface where a user can click on the image, and it tracks the % from the left, and % from the top. Then, allow the user to increase the width/height, while tracking what % of the total image height each region is. You'll store these four coordinates in a database record along with a reference to the full image, and each region image.